# Flash when changing to dark/light mode dynamically

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, android-night-mode

I have a requirement that when a switch is clicked, I need to invert the mode from dark to light and vice versa respectively. But the twist part is, that I do not want to finish the activity and restart it as I don't want the flash/flicker of activity recreation to be noticed by the user. Hence, I use `Activity.this.recreate()`. Now, this works well in all API levels and phones I checked so far. But, in **Android Pie**, it shows a kind of flash even while using `Activity.this.recreate()`

Anyone please suggest me some way to solve the issue in **Android Pie**, or some better way to approach my concern.

Comment: You can restart your activity normally with `finish` and then calling `startActivity()` & then call `overridePendingTransition()` & pass your required animation. for e.g. (fade in, fade out)

Comment: This does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You are right that it flashes in Android Pie (9.0) when we use "recreate()" method to re-start activity. To solve this problem we can do as below, I have tested it successfully with Android Pie (9.0) and the flash removed.

Use "overridePendingTransition(0,0)" and start self activity without using "recreate()" method.

Here is the code:

```
var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
overridePendingTransition(0,0)
```

Comment: This answer is not correct, it is keeping the old activity in the backstack since `finish();` is never called for the current activity, which will cause the "flash" issue to return once it is used, going back to the problem pointed out in the question.